# Working with MySQL in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, multithreading

In newer versions of Android using internet tasks in the main thread are not allowed. To use it you have to create a new thread. Using threads will not come without problems.

I have a simple class that connects to my MySQL database. It initializes a `connection` variable containing a `java.sql.Connection` object. I have a `getConnection` method that returns the object.

In the main thread I want to be able to query the database:

```
PreparedStatement query = this.dbManager.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT ...");
```

Because the database class, `DatabaseManager`, implements Runnable and I have created a thread using it, I'm not able to call that method: it has no effect.

```
this.dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
new Thread(this.dbManager).start();
```

How am I able to call methods in the thread? For example, when a user clicks an add button in the UI the program should show a waiting icon, execute a query and hide the icon.

Comment: You've had a look at subclassing AsyncTask? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: In this case, wouldn't you have to initialize a new connection every time you want to do something with the database?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. No chance of using a webservice or similar? Think you'll have to write your own client.

Comment: Actually, you could write a Service, that would work. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Have that do all your network stuff, speak to it from UI only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use `ContentProviders`, `ContentObservers`, and `CursorLoaders`, and perhaps `SyncAdapter`. It's quite a lot to cover in one post, but essentially...

- `ContentProvider` is used to access data in your app's local SQLite database on the device
- `ContentObserver`s monitor URIs for changes so you can take action when data in your database changes
- `CursorLoader`s will make a database query off the UI thread and return you the results, and also registers a ContentObserver so it can requery when that data changes (it does this transparently on your behalf)
- `SyncAdapter` lets you perform sync operations periodically

Find the source code to the Google I/O app, they use all of the above. You can find it online, just search for "iosched source".

Comment: I need to use an external MySQL database. Not going to work with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `IntentService` and use it for your network call. When you start the service, it's `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` method is called with the Intent you used to start it. Everything done in that method is processed off the main thread.

To handle calling back to the UI thread you can do either of the following:

1. Send a broadcast `Intent` when your `IntentService` is finished processing and have it include information about the result of your network call. Define a `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity that listens for that broadcast. Register it in `onStart()` and unregister it in `onStop()`.
2. Create a custom `Handler` for your `Activity` and create a `Messenger` object for it. When you make the `Intent` to start the service, package the `Messenger` as en extra in the Intent. When your `IntentService` is done, use that to call back to the `Handler` in your `Activity`.